# Django: Possible to use variable from parent for loop within child if statement

Tags: django, django-templates, webapp2

Is it possible to use a variable from the parent's for loop within the child's if statement?

This is the example:

```
{% for ruleset in rulesets %}
  <div>{{ ruleset.0 }}</div>
  <ul>
    {% for rule in rules %}
      {% if rule.0 = {{ ruleset.0 }} %}
        <li>{{ rule.1 }}</li>
      {% else %}
        <!-- Nothing -->
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

The error I am getting is:
raise TemplateSyntaxError("Could not parse the remainder: '%s' from '%s'" % (token[upto:], token))
TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'

Which I presume means that it couldn't understand {{ ruleset.0 }} within the if statement. Any  suggestions as to how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect: you can't  use `{{ ... }}` inside a `{% ... %}` statement.

This should work, as the inner for loop should inherit the scope of the outer for loop:

```
{% for ruleset in rulesets %}
<div>{{ ruleset.0 }}</div>
<ul>
  {% for rule in rules %}
    # = is an assignment operator (which doesn't work in templates),
    # == is the equality operator, which you want to use.
    # alternatively you can use {% ifequal rule.0 ruleset.0 %}{% else %}{% endifequal %}
    {% if rule.0 == ruleset.0  %} 
      <li>{{ rule.1 }}</li>
    {% else %}
      <!-- Nothing -->
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you also miss another `{% endfor %}` tag in the end of the inner nested loop

Comment: @GabrielAmram Good catch. Just say your answer, do you know if `forloop.parent` is required to access variables in the parent's for loop scope, or is it just a way to access the parent's for loop `counter`, `counter0` etc?

Comment: @kbnk It is indeed to get the counter0, counter etc... this is why I deleted my answer, as it is not what was originally asked..